# JavaScript Weird Parts: What is the use of the expression " ; (function() { .../////... }());"

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please explain what is the meaning/use of this following expression in JavaScript.Is it advantageous ?

```
; (function() {....//..... }());
```

Note the use of semi-colon before the function declaration.Can it be used , I know its related to IIFE(immediately invoked function Expression)...Can Someone shed some more light on the usage of these declarations.

Comment: Try to use 2 IIFEs or a function followed by an IIFE. It will throw an error. Intermediate value does not exists. For this it a good convention to use `;` before IIFE

Comment: @bergi that is what i was searching to close it as duplicate.